# Open Source AI Bot interfaces

Tags: ai, bot

What are some open source AI Bot interfaces?  Similar to **[Pogamut 3 GameBots2004](http://diana.ms.mff.cuni.cz/main/tiki-index.php)** for custom Unreal Tournament bots or **[Brood Wars API](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi/)** for Starcraft bots etc.

If you could please post one AI bot interface per answer (make sure to provide a link) and give a brief summary as to the content of the blog posts.

Please include what type of bot interface structure it is, client/server, server/server, etc

e.g. **BWAPI** is client/server which emulates a real player

Answer (score 4):

**[Planet Wars / Galcon Clone AI](http://ai-contest.com/)**

Ran as a **Google AI Challenge**

> Planet Wars is a strategy game set in outer space. The objective is to take over all the planets on the map, or altenatively eliminate all of your opponents ships.
>
> Players start with 1-3 home planets and send off ships to conquer other planets around them. The numbers on each planet indicate how many ships it will take to conquer them. The numbers on a player's own planet indicate the amount of ships that their planet holds. Each planet a player owns produces ships for that player with more ships at a faster rate produced depending on the planet's size. Players can select what percentage of the ships to send from a planet and players can redirect ships in midair. The aim of the game is to defeat the other opponent(s).

Implemented as a **Server/Server** architecture you can implement your AI bot in C++/Java/Python/C#/Go/etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

**[image: Brood Wars Application Programming Interface (BWAPI)]**

Brood Wars API is a dll injection type interface which natively is Server/Server design but also has extensions to support Client/Server architectures for additional language support.

Extensions support Java, Python, C#, Php, etc.

> The Brood War Application Programming Interface (BWAPI) is a free and open source C++ framework for creating AI modules for Starcraft: Broodwar. Using BWAPI, programmers can retrieve information on players and individual units in Starcraft as well as issue a wide variety of commands to units, opening the doors for custom AIs with new micro and macro algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

**[Pogamut 3 GameBots2004](http://diana.ms.mff.cuni.cz/main/tiki-index.php)**

Extension of the original GameBots work done by USC which supports UT2004/ UDK/ and Defcon.  Allows an external program to control bots in game in a **Client/Server** fashion as if they were a human player.

> External control mechanisms can be connected to many of these games using the scripting languages, thereby providing a tool to control the in-game characters from the outside. Pogamut utilizes UnrealScript (UT2004 scripting language) in this way and also NetBeans Java platform to provide an out-of-the box development environment for AI of virtual characters inhabiting **UT2004**, **Unreal Development Kit (UDK)** and **DEFCON** worlds.

Answer (score 1):

**[image: MarioAI]**

The **[Mario AI](http://www.marioai.org/)** Allows you to implement an AI Agent to control Mario.  Different levels of map details are available to allow a simple implementation or implementations with near engine level map details.  The API is a server/server type implementation using Java.

Additionally a Level Generation API is provided for creating user generated levels.